# Did Valmiki ever meet Lord Rama prior to the Ashwamedha?

Tags: ramayana, rama, valmiki

I came across a question on this site about Veda Vyasa, the author of Mahabharat, meeting Lord Krishna and I was wondering if similarly Valmiki also met Lord Rama sometime. They have met at the time of the Ashwamedha Yagna when Luv and Kush defeated Lord Rama's army but I want to know if they ever met before in life?

Comment: *They have met at the time of the Ashwamedha Yagna when Luv and Kush defeated Lord Rama's army*            from where/ which text you got this?

Comment: @hanugm May be I think OP got the idea from similar sites like this one .The author exaggerated many things in this article. https://sites.google.com/site/grandfatherstales/part-1 ,  I think these  stories are intended for small kids who just needs to introduce names like Rama and Valmiki , i think .

Comment: @SwiftPushkar Yeah.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Ayodhya Kanda it was mentioned that before constructing their hermitage on Chitrakuta mountain, Sri Rama, Sita and Lakshmana met Sage Valmiki.

> इति सीता च रामश्च लक्ष्मणश्च कृताञ्जलिः |
>   अभिगम्याश्रमम् सर्वे **वाल्मीकि** मभिवादयन् || २-५६-१६
>
> After deciding thus Seetha, Rama and Lakshmana all with joined palms approached the hermitage and offered salutation to the sage Valmiki.
>
> तान्महर्षिः प्रमुदितः पूजयामास धर्मवित् |
>   आस्यतामिति चोवाच स्वागतम् तु निवेद्य च || २-५६-१७
>
> The great sage Valmiki, who knew what is right, full of delight, treated them with honour, offered cordial welcome and requested them to sit.

&&&&&&&&

Ramayana was silent as to whether the poet Valmiki, who wrote Ramayana, and the Sage Valmiki that Sri Rama met at Chitrakuta mountain are one and the same.

Comment: Those verses seem out of place in that chapter and are clearly interpolations. Also, not present in [Bibek Debroy's translation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFRyZ.png) based on the critical edition.

Comment: Oh wo this is interesting! Thanks for sharing